# Magento - Check if category is enabled in template file

Tags: php, magento

Is there a method of checking if a certain category is enabled from within Magento template files?  I only want to show a link to a specific category if it is currently enabled.  Something like:

```
if($categoryID(123)->isEnabled()){
    // Do something because category ID 123 is enabled...
}
```

I need to apply this in the header, so it would be used on every page.

Appreciate any assistance.  I'm sure this is very simple but I have not been able to find anything that is leading me down the right path on this.

Thanks.

Comment: is category id is static?

Comment: Yes, they're static.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it very simple

just use this

```
$specificCatID = '90';
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($specificCatID);
if ($category->getIsActive()) {

// Do something because category ID  is enabled...


}
```

source http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/03/check-if-category-is-enabled-or-not-in.html

Comment: Thank you, worked perfectly.  I do something similar for products, so why I didn't apply this to categories I just don't know.